# add two complex numbers, but the result will be returned to another object of the same class in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Returning Objects from a method

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
class ComplexNos 
{ 
 private int x,y; 
 ComplexNos(int a,int b) 
{ 
 x=a; 
 y=b; 
}  
ComplexNos add (ComplexNos a) //method Returns an object 
{ 
 ComplexNos c=new ComplexNos();// iam getting an error here 
 c.x=x+a.x; 
 c.y=y+a.y; 
 return c; 
} 
void display() 
{ 
 if(y>=0) 
 System.out.println(x+"+i"+y); 
 else 
 System.out.println(x + "" + y +"i"); 
} 
} 
class ObjectReturn 
{ 
 public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
 int a,b; 
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
 System.out.println("Enter real and imaginary part of a complex number:"); 
 a=sc.nextInt(); 
 b=sc.nextInt(); 
 ComplexNos c1=new ComplexNos(a,b); 
 System.out.println("Enter real and imaginary part of another complex 
 number:"); 
 a=sc.nextInt(); 
 b=sc.nextInt(); 
 ComplexNos c2=new ComplexNos(a,b); 
 ComplexNos c3 = new ComplexNos();//iam getting an error here
 c3=c1.add(c2); //Storing new value in object c3 
 c3.display();  
System.out.println("Value of the 1st object is: "); 
c1.display(); 
System.out.println("Value of the 2nd object is: "); 
c2.display(); 
} 
}

output:

    ObjectReturn.java:12: error: constructor ComplexNos in class ComplexNos cannot b
    e applied to given types;
     ComplexNos c=new ComplexNos();
                  ^
      required: int,int
      found: no arguments
      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    ObjectReturn.java:39: error: constructor ComplexNos in class ComplexNos cannot b
    e applied to given types;
     ComplexNos c3 = new ComplexNos();
                     ^
      required: int,int
      found: no arguments
      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    2 errors
```

iam a beginner so i cant understand whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to instantiate a ComplexNos object using a constructor that it doesn't have.

When you call

```
ComplexNos c=new ComplexNos();
```

It's looking for a constructor that looks like

```
ComplexNos() { 
    //some code
}
```

But it can't find that in your code.

The solution, is to either create a default no argument constructor like the one above, or to refactor your creation of the c variable to use a constructor you already have (like the one with two numbers there).